# http to https redirection multiple sites

Tags: iis, https, http, redirect

I use IIS10 and I want to redirect all HTTP to HTTPS for all my sites.

For example:

- `http://one.test.example` should be redirected to `https://one.test.example`
- `http://two.test.example` should be redirected to `https://two.test.example`
- `http://three.test.example` should be redirected to `https://three.test.example`

All the sites are in one server behind one interface (same IP, same 443 port)

I tried multiple solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: "I tried multiple solutions but nothing worked." this does no explain what you did try and how it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Use this web.config file on root folder of your subdomains.
This will Rewrite all requests to https with query strings.

Comment: I've tried this myself and it doesn't work. The url rewrite will work for one site, but then all others stop working.. fix it for one of the others, and the original stopped working. URL Rewrite is a pretty patchy solution at best. There's gotta be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you would need to create a separate site in IIS for each domain and the rules respectively. Check the [configuring rewrite rules article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules#configuring-rewrite-rules) for some examples. Also, you need to download and install [URL Rewrite modules](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). If you are on a server, checkout how to install the modules on [Windows Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/#setup)